# How to arrange multiple multivariate time series of different length before passing it to Keras LSTM layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, data-preprocessing

I have a number of multivariate time series that are produced by the same kind of process but:

- are of significantly different lengths;
- each time series is an independent instance, and the measurements are taken at different, quite random timestamps;
- each time series is related at every timestamp to two targets.

In other words:

- each time series has a shape of `(n_timestamps, n_features)`
- each target series has a shape of `(n_timestamps, 2)`.

To give an example, this could be treated as stocks of different companies, that are described by few various features and the target at a given timestamp are probabilities that the final price at the end of the year will be higher than x, except we learn them directly from magically given ground-truth probabilities (instead of observed 0/1 responses).

I want to be able to predict the target at each time point and I wanted to give RNNs a try. However, I'm having issues with figuring out how I should arrange the data before passing it to Keras LSTM layers. The main things I'm wondering about are:

1. I want my RNN to use data starting from the beginning of the series to make prediction at time `t`, not only last `k` timestamps. I can't really use the whole history directly without exploding the gradient (it's too long), therefore I need a way to "remember" previously learned weights even though in reality my RNN will loop over last `k` timestamps.
2. Each time series has different length, so I'm unsure how to make things compatible with each other. I'm aware of padding as an option, but since the difference in length of examples can be as significant as 1000 vs 3000 this will results in many training examples that constitutes only of padding value.
3. Since measurements are taken at different timestamps, I believe it may affect my network in a sense that it can't really learn that e.g. last 10 timestamps are the most important. Or even if it can, these last 10 timestamps will have different lengths in reality for each input time-series... How big problem is this? Should I start with resampling all examples to the same time points (e.g. by interpolating)?

My current thinking is that:

- I can pad each of my example sequences to the same length (`max(n_timestamps)`)
- Create batches of short sequences of length `k`, where `k` represents the length of the loop of RNN layer. In consequence, assuming I have 200 example sequences with the longest one has 3000 timestamps and my selected `k` is 50, it would result in `3000/50=60` batches of `(200, 50)` shape. Or should I make `3000-1` batches where one batch differs from the next one only by one timestamp (i.e. while the fist batch has timestamps from 1 to 50, the next batch has timestamps from 2 to 51 etc.)?
- Since padding was used, I would need to use Masking layer. Some (quite many) of the rows in prepared batches would constitute of inputs that should be ignored completely (as they would only have padding value for all 50 elements).

Is this the correct way to prepare the data for my problem? Can it be done better to not introduce bottlenecks such as learning using examples of only padding value (that should be ignored with masking layer). Or how can I prepare that data to address points 1., 2. and 3. described above?

Comment: // I've read that I could treat each of my time series as a separate batch. Therefore, I guess my input array that I would pass as `X_train` would be of shape `(n_time_series, max_t(n_timestamps_t), n_features)`. //                                                                              
If you treat each time series as a separate batch, why would you need to pad it?

Comment: your `Y_train` should be `(n_time_series, 2)`. Each element in a `X_train` batch maps to a class, i assume that's what you are trying to do based on 2 being present.

Comment: You should provide a MWE for people to help you better.

Comment: This question does not belong to SO. But, for
> each time series is an independent instance, and the measurements are taken at different, quite random timestamps;

Sounds like resampling and interpolation to me, to get the shared time index across multiple time series instances

Answer (score 0):

> each time series has a shape of (n_timestamps, n_features)
> each target series has a shape of (n_timestamps, 2).

Okay, this is pretty standard so far.

> I want my RNN to use data starting from the beginning of the series to make prediction at time t, not only last k timestamps. I can't really use the whole history directly without exploding the gradient (it's too long), therefore I need a way to "remember" previously learned weights even though in reality my RNN will loop over last k timestamps.

Check and make sure you actually need this. An RNN (or a Transformer) could use any of/all of the history that you give it. But that's assuming that the history is useful for the predictions you're making.

I'd try training on standard-sized random-clips of the data (like in [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#multi-output_models)). I'd retrain it a few times with longer and longer clips and see if the model performance plateaus before I run out of memory.

But in Keras it is relatively simple to do exactly the thing you're asking.

Keras RNNs (LSTM, GRU) have these this argument `return_states`. It allows you to allows you to run the model over part of a sequence, pause, execute a training step, and then continue running exactly where you left off.

(and `stateful` argument is another mechanism to provide that effect)

The code ends up looking something like this:

```
class MyModel(keras.Model):
  ...

  def train_step(self, args):
    inputs, labels = args
    state = self.get_initial_state()
    while tf.shape(inputs)[1] != 0:
      in_slice, inputs = inputs[:,:100], inputs[:,100:]
      label_slice, labels = labels[:, :100], labels[:,100:]

      with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        result, state = self(in_slice, state)

        loss = self.loss(label_slice, result)

      vars = self.trainable_variables
      grads = tape.gradient(loss, vars)
      self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, vars))
```

It may also be possible to use [ForwardAccumulator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/autodiff/ForwardAccumulator) to collect the gradients. In that case you don't need to cut the sequences into chunks because the memory used by forward accumulator doesn't grow with sequence length. I've never tried before so I don't have example code.

> Each time series has different length, so I'm unsure how to make things compatible with each other. I'm aware of padding as an option, but since the difference in length of examples can be as significant as 1000 vs 3000 this will results in many training examples that constitutes only of padding value.

That might be okay, just inefficient. You can make batches of similar sequence lengths using: [Dataset.bucket_by_sequence_length](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#bucket_by_sequence_length)

> Since measurements are taken at different timestamps, I believe it may affect my network in a sense that it can't really learn that e.g. last 10 timestamps are the most important. Or even if it can, these last 10 timestamps will have different lengths in reality for each input time-series... How big problem is this? Should I start with resampling all examples to the same time points (e.g. by interpolating)?

Interpolating to a fixed rate might be a resonable thing to try if it doesn't make your data too much longer. Just think carefully about making predictions on interpolated values: There's some data leaking back in time from a future measurement.

Another approach would be to make the size of the time-step a feature. If each input is tagged with how long it's been since the last input the model can learn how to handle small or large steps.

> I can pad each of my example sequences to the same length (max(n_timestamps))

Yes. Pad, or make clips of a fixed size.

> Create batches of short sequences of length k, where k represents the length of the loop of RNN layer. In consequence, assuming I have 200 example sequences with the longest one has 3000 timestamps and my selected k is 50, it would result in 3000/50=60 batches of (200, 50) shape.

That would line up with the code example I gave.

> Or should I make 3000-1 batches where one batch differs from the next one only by one timestamp

Either way is fine. But if you want to carry the state over from batch to batch (I'm skeptical that you actually need the carry over) then you need to do them chunk by chunk, not by single-stepping your window.

> Since padding was used, I would need to use Masking layer. Some (quite many) of the rows in prepared batches would constitute of inputs that should be ignored completely (as they would only have padding value for all 50 elements).

Yeah, that'll be wasted computation, but it won't hurt anything.